# Public Nodes that Work with web3 Filters

Tags: web3js, nodes, python

I am attempting to connect to the Ethereum blockchain and monitor transactions as they are broadcasted. I don't have the capability to run a full node on my computer, so I am relying on "third party" nodes to connect to the blockchain. The two that I have been trying are "https://mainnet.infura.io/ [MY PRIVATE KEY]" and "https://api.myetherapi.com/eth". To retrieve newest transactions I am using the web3 python module filters. However, when I execute this code, as inspired by [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35559/best-way-to-track-block-transactions-as-they-happen) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36009/web3-py-eventfilter-get-new-entries-always-empty):

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import time

node = #DEPENDS
connection = Web3(HTTPProvider(node))

block_filter = connection.eth.filter('latest')

time.sleep(60) #OR LONGER
print(block_filter.get_all_entries())
```

If my node is the infuria one, I get the error "requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://mainnet.infura.io/ [MY PRIVATE KEY]". If I use the myetherapi one, the result is simply an empty list.

Are there any other HTTP nodes that I could use to connect to the blockchain? Or is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that problem is not in your code. I have the same issue: tried to use infura and Filter() on Python. Unfortunately, [infura don't provide this method at the moment](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/13), but it will be in the future as they said.

What you can do:

1) trying another public node (google it or look here https://www.ethernodes.org/)

2) create your own node (as I decided to do) — simpliest way to do it here https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/